# Create QImage from buffer, no deep copy?

Tags: c++, qt

in Qt, how can I construct a `QImage` object from a byte array ('uint8_t*`), without creating a deep copy, just referring to my data array?

Comment: I'm unsure this is possible, [the docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qimage.html#loadFromData) suggest this way of loading a byte array, which most likely copies due to the length parameter, and perhaps mutates the data, which is why it performs a deep copy?

Comment: The `QImage::QImage(const uchar * data, int width, int height, Format format)` from the docs looks to me like there is no deep copy. I mean ***The buffer must remain valid throughout the life of the QImage and all copies that have not been modified or otherwise detached from the original buffer. The image does not delete the buffer at destruction***

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use any of the constructors which take a `uchar *`, for instance

```
QImage::QImage(uchar *data, 
               int width, 
               int height, 
               int bytesPerLine, 
               Format format, 
               QImageCleanupFunction cleanupFunction = Q_NULLPTR, 
               void *cleanupInfo = Q_NULLPTR)
```

As the documentation says:

> **The buffer must remain valid throughout the life of the QImage and all copies that have not been modified or otherwise detached from the original buffer. The image does not delete the buffer at destruction.** You can provide a function pointer cleanupFunction along with an extra pointer cleanupInfo that will be called when the last copy is destroyed.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Do you have any idea on how to create a `QPixmap` from that `QImage` without deep copying anything?

Comment: QPixmap is another story (why do you need that?). While it's _likely_ that a QImage in the right format won't cause a deep copy when converting to QPixmap, you can't rely on that. The idea is that a QPixmap holds a "server-side" pixmap, such as a X pixmap, therefore a copy was needed. Now since Qt 5 server-side drawing code was removed from Qt, so a QPixmap is actually backed by a QImage, in the preferred format for showing on the display. Which format exactly becomes a bit of implementation detail. If you dig in the code and maybe guess it right, then no copies will be necessary.

Comment: Nice explanation! I need a `QPixmap` because I am creating an image visualizer similar to the one in http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-imageviewer-example.html